# How to show div in multiple lines instead one line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have centered the `div` contents in a wrapper using `display:flex`. now the problem is the child divs are showing in one line, but I wanted to make it displayed above each other. here is my code:

```css
.news-content-inner{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    width:300px;
}
.news-by-category-items > .news-content-inner > .category-tags{
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 2px 8px; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
.news-by-category-items > .news-content-inner > .news-title{
    font-size: 16px; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
.news-by-category-items > .news-content-inner >  .news-date{
    font-size:14px; color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-content-inner">
  <div class="category-tags tag3">block level text 1</div>
  <div class="news-title">block level text 2 </div>
  <div class="news-date">block level text 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - are you looking for `flex-direction`, or - what …?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for flex-direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `flex-direction: column;`

```css
.news-content-inner{
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center; 
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    width:300px;
}
.news-by-category-items > .news-content-inner > .category-tags{
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 2px 8px; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
.news-by-category-items > .news-content-inner > .news-title{
    font-size: 16px; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
.news-by-category-items > .news-content-inner >  .news-date{
    font-size:14px; color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-content-inner">
  <div class="category-tags tag3">block level text 1</div>
  <div class="news-title">रblock level text 2 </div>
  <div class="news-date">block level text 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I was missing this and completely lost about it, thanks!